# How to copy the content of several files into other files

Tags: python

I'm trying to read several txt files, count the words, put everything in a dictionary and then, write said dictionary in a new text file but i'm having trouble with the `for` loops. When I execute the program, all the new files have the exact same content and I don't understand why.

Here's what I have written for now :

```
filename = ['file1.txt', 'file2.txt', 'file3.txt']
newfilename = ['newfile1.txt', 'newfile2.txt', 'newfile3.txt']

for l in filename :
    f = open(l, mode = 'r')
    dic = {}
    text = f.readlines()
    for t in text :
        word = sorted(t.split(), key = str.lower)
        for w in word :
            if w not in dic:
                dic[w] = 1
            else :
                dic[w] += 1
    dicsort = sorted(dic.items(), key = operator.itemgetter(1), reverse = True)
    for l2 in newfilename :
        f2 = open(l2, mode = 'w', encoding = 'utf-8')
        for k, v in dicsort :
            f2.write('\t'+ str(k) + '\t\t' + str(v)+'\n')
```

Edit : Thank you ! I used `zip` and opened the files using `with`and now it works ! :)

Here's the final code :

```
filename = ['file1.txt', 'file2.txt', 'file3.txt']
newfilename = ['newfile1.txt', 'newfile2.txt', 'newfile3.txt']

for l, l2 in zip(filename, newfilename) :
    with open(l, mode = 'r') as f:
        with open(l2, mode = 'w', encoding = 'utf-8') as f2 :
            dic = {}
            text = f.readlines()
            for t in text :
                word = sorted(t.split(), key = str.lower)
                for w in word :
                    if w not in dic:
                        dic[w] = 1
                    else :
                        dic[w] += 1
            dicsort = sorted(dic.items(), key = operator.itemgetter(1), reverse = True)
            for k, v in dicsort :
            f2.write('\t'+ str(k) + '\t\t' + str(v)+'\n')
```

Comment: **The** for-loop? I see five. Also, "having trouble" is rather imprecise.

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: One suggestion: do `for old_name, new_name in zip(filename, newfilename): ...`

Comment: Can you provide some examples of the text inside the files and what you expect the output to contain?

Comment: The reason why your output files contain all of the same data is because each time you dictionary is generated and you write it to the file, you run a loop `for l2 in newfilename:` and inside that loop you have `f2 = open(l2, mode = 'w', encoding = 'utf-8')`.. so your loop will iterate over every output file and open the file with `mode='w'` and this will erase the previous information from the file.. so the only information in your output files will be from the very last iteration

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this. Each text file in `filename` has: *There is some great great text here*

```
import operator

filename = ['file1.txt', 'file2.txt', 'file3.txt']
newfilename = ['newfile1.txt', 'newfile2.txt', 'newfile3.txt']

for old, new in zip(filename, newfilename):
    dic = dict()    
    with open(old) as o, open(new, 'w') as n:
        words = o.read().split()
        for word in words:
            if word in dic:
                dic[word] += 1
            else:
                dic[word] = 1

        dicsort = sorted(dic.items(), key=operator.itemgetter(1), reverse=True)

        for k, v in dicsort:
            n.write('\t'+ k + '\t\t' + str(v) + '\n') # No need to call `str()` on `k` as `k` is already a string.
```

Output written to each text file in `newfilename`:

```
    great       2
    There       1
    is          1
    some        1
    text        1
    here        1
```

Answer (score 0):

Note: not meant to be a complete answer, but hopefully I can prevent some beginner mistakes.

1. Never, ever open a file outside of a `with` statement. This is very bad.
2. You can iterate directly over a file object.

So, the revised (but still non-working) code would be:

```
filename = ['file1.txt', 'file2.txt', 'file3.txt']
newfilename = ['newfile1.txt', 'newfile2.txt', 'newfile3.txt']
for l in filename :
    dic = {}
    with open(l, 'r') as fp:
        for t in fp :
            word = sorted(t.split(), key = str.lower)
            for w in word :
                if w not in dic:
                    dic[w] = 1
                else :
                    dic[w] += 1
    dicsort = sorted(dic.items(), key = operator.itemgetter(1), reverse = True)
    for l2 in newfilename :
        with open(l2, mode = 'w', encoding = 'utf-8') as fp:
            for k, v in dicsort :
                fp.write('\t'+ str(k) + '\t\t' + str(v)+'\n')
```

Answer (score 0):

I'll try to explain what your current code does with pseudocode:

```
for each input file:
  count its words
  for each output file:
    record the word count in the file
```

From here, it should be obvious that for each input file, the output files **all** get replaced with the word count, so by the last input file, the outputs will all have the counts for that file.

To fix  this, you could use the zip function.

It works something like this: `zip([1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6]) == [(1, 4), (2, 5), (3, 6)]`.

You can use it like this:

```
for input_file, output_file in zip(input_files, output_files):
  count words in input
  write to output
```

Then the word count will only be written in one file.

Answer (score 0):

You are overwritting your files over and over again. I find it easier to create the new files with names on the fly instead of pre-defining. A working version of your code above is,

```
filename = ['file1.txt', 'file2.txt', 'file3.txt']

for count, l in enumerate(filename):
   f = open(l, mode='r')
   dic = {}
   text = f.readlines()
   for t in text:
      word = sorted(t.split(), key=str.lower)
      for w in word:
         if w.lower() not in dic:
             dic[w.lower()] = 1
         else:
             dic[w.lower()] += 1
   dicsort = sorted(dic.items(), reverse=True)
   print dicsort
   f2 = open('newfile'+str(count+1)+'.txt', mode='w')
   for k, v in dicsort:
      f2.write('\t' + str(k) + '\t\t' + str(v)+'\n')
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

If this is not homework, then you can use the `collections.Counter` class to simplify. As for splitting the file contents into words, I prefer to use regular expression to get all the words at once:

```
import collections
import re

filename = ['file1.txt', 'file2.txt', 'file3.txt']
newfilename = ['newfile1.txt', 'newfile2.txt', 'newfile3.txt']

pattern = re.compile(r'\w+')
for infilename, outfilename in zip(filename, newfilename):
    with open(infilename) as inf, open(outfilename, 'w') as outf:
        words = re.findall(pattern, inf.read().lower())
        counter = collections.Counter(words)
        for k, v in counter.most_common():
            outf.write('\t{}\t\t{}\n'.format(k, v))
```

In my approach, I use `re.findall()` to get all the lowercase words out in one line. Keep in mind that this line consists of 3 separate functions calls: `.read()` to read the file contents, `.lower()` to turn the whole contents into lower case, and `re.findall()` to extract all the words.

After that, I used the `collections.Counter` class to count these words, the result `counter` acts like a dictionary. This `Counter` object includes `.most_common()` method which returns a list of words and count in descending order, very convenient.

The last thing to do is to write them out.

Overall, this approach makes use of the standard libraries to get things done in about 10 lines of code.